# average over columns for the matrix with Nan values

Tags: matlab, mean

I have the matrix below:

```
rmat =

     1     2     3   NaN   NaN   NaN
     1     2     3     4     5   NaN
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

is there any way to calculate the average of the coulmns that has value: for i.e in the first column `(1+1+1+1)/4=0.25` and just skip Nan and for the second column `(2+2+2)/3=2` and so on...

Any advice will be highly appriciated

Comment: Umm...[`nanmean(rmat,2)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html) ?

Comment: Thanks and sorry for my silly question!

Comment: Also `mean(rmat, 1, 'omitnan')`, which doesn't require the Statistics Toolbox

Answer (score 2):

The `nanmean()` function sounds like what you might be after: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/nanmean.html